# How can I split one field into two using Insert Into?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to split one field into two fields using Insert Into.  Here is my code.

```
INSERT INTO Pricing (ID_GLOBAL, 
    PRICING_SOURCE,
    PX_BID,
    PX_ASK,
    PX_HIGH,
    PX_LOW,
    PX_OPEN,
    CASE WHEN W.id_cd = 'ISN' THEN ID_ISN = W.id_number
         ELSE ID_SED = W.id_number 
         END)
Select C.asset_id,  
    C.price_source, 
    C.bid_price, 
    C.ask_price, 
    C.high, 
    C.low, 
    C.open_price, 
    W.id_cd, 
    W.id_number
From RRS As C
INNER JOIN ERS As W
ON C.asset_id = W.asset_id
```

Everything worked fine before I put the CASE in there.  Now, I'm getting this error:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'CASE'.
```

Comment: The `CASE` expression goes in the `SELECT`, not in the column list.

Comment: CASE is an expression. It is used to return a single value. It cannot be used to decide which column to insert into like this.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  So, what is the logic to test for W.id_cd = 'ISN' or W.id_cd = 'SED', and based on the results of that, ID_ISN = W.id_number or ID_SED = W.id_number.  That's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to create a conditional list of columns to insert into. You have specify all the columns you may have values for and then conditionally populate them. So, you'll need to two CASE statements in your SELECT statement to populate those two columns appropriately.

Try the following (note: I didn't actually run this, so let me know if there any minor syntax errors).

```
INSERT INTO Pricing (ID_GLOBAL, 
    PRICING_SOURCE,
    PX_BID,
    PX_ASK,
    PX_HIGH,
    PX_LOW,
    PX_OPEN,
    ID_ISN,
    ID_SED)
Select C.asset_id,  
    C.price_source, 
    C.bid_price, 
    C.ask_price, 
    C.high, 
    C.low, 
    C.open_price, 
    W.id_cd, 
    CASE WHEN W.id_cd = 'ISN' THEN W.id_number ELSE NULL END,
    CASE WHEN W.id_cd != 'ISN' THEN W.id_number ELSE NULL END
From RRS As C
INNER JOIN ERS As W
ON C.asset_id = W.asset_id
```